# How to correctly set Vim's makeprg (Windows)

Tags: windows, cmd, vim

In Linux, I've used this `au FileType c set makeprg=gcc\ -o\ %<` in my .vimrc to set my default compiler for .c files, and this: `nmap <F5> :<C-U>silent make %<CR>:redraw!<CR>:!./%<<CR>` to bind F5 key to make things faster.

How should I do this on Windows? I've tried with `au FileType c set makeprg="cmd /c C:\tcc\tcc.exe -o %<"` and some few other samples, but none have worked.

In brief: I want to hit `F5` to compile&run program in cmd or cmd with errors that compiler gave.

I'd appreciate any hints how to get this thing work on Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include cmd.exe on `'makeprg'`.
The line you use in Linux should work fine if gcc is in your path.

Another approach could be using [Single Compile plugin](http://www.topbug.net/blog/2012/03/07/use-singlecompile-to-compile-and-run-a-single-source-file-easily-in-vim/) to simplify the mapping to <kbd>F5</kbd>.